# Is it possible to perform planned actions with laravel?

Tags: laravel

I was wondering if there is a way to perform planned actions with laravel, for example at 15 of every month peform an action (send an email for example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Laravel 5 this is already integrated, if you use L4, you can use dispacther as sugested by @pespantelis.

In the case you mention you can do this:

In a cron format:

```
<?php
$schedule->command('sendMyEmailCommand')->cron('0 0 15 * *');
```

In a more expressive Laravel way:

```
<?php
$schedule->command('sendMyEmailCommand')->monthly()->when(function()
{
    return (date("d") == 15);
});
```

See the related [laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/artisan#scheduling-artisan-commands) for detail and guiadance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the [dispatcher](https://github.com/Indatus/dispatcher).

> Dispatcher is a Laravel artisan command scheduling tool used to schedule artisan commands within your project so you don't need to touch your crontab when deploying.